# how to use the cross domain xml file with my project

Tags: cross-domain

```
I have a xml file. how can i use the xml file and access the cross domain request in angularjs $http request.

<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
/* cross-domain contents goes here */
</cross-domain-poliy>
```

How can i use this xml file with my project and make the cross domain access to true.

Answer (score 0):

A CrossDomain.xml file allows a Flash app to make HTTP calls to a domain that is different than the one the SWF is served from.  Usually this is used to make calls to remote services, but could also be used to load assets.  The crossdomain.xml file will have no affect on HTML or JavaScript code.

If you want to make an AngularJS service call to a different domain than you have to use JSONP.  The easiest way to do this from an AngularJS app is to use the [$http.jsonp()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#jsonp) method.  Be careful, though, as doing this is a form of [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Site_Scripting).  My preference is that production sites do not make use of JSONP.  It can be useful for development purposes, though.

Comment: This will only work for GET requests.  A better solution would be to make use of CORS.